# Density of stochastic integral

Tags: probability-distributions, stochastic-integrals

I am working on finding the PDF of $X_t^2$,

where $X_t = \int_0^t A(u) \,dW_u$, a Wiener integral, i.e., $W_t$ is Brownian motion and $A(t)$ is a deterministic function.

Here, would like to ask that do you guys have any idea about what does 
the PDF of $X_t^2$ look like, or how to find it ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: it is a wiener integral, in this case, $X_t$ is a centred Gaussian variable with variance $\int_0^t A(u)^2 \, du$. Then it is not difficult to calculate the desired density ?

Answer (score 1):

You can determine the sde that $X_t^2$ satisfies using Ito's lemma.  Then you can find the pdf by solving the forward Kolmogorov equations (Fokker-Planck).

Comment: Thank you, I will try your suggested method.

Comment: muaddib, do you need all that? What about what @Chival said? (Is what he said a result of the things you said?)

Comment: It's how to solve the problem in general.  What he said isn't right as the resulting sde has a drift and his solution doesn't.